# Flex compiler appears to misinterpret .as files as MXML

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

After changing the Flex SDK to 3.6 (from 4.5.1) so as to target Flash player 9.0.124, the project no longer compiles, producing spurious errors such as `XML does not have matching begin and end tags` leading me to believe that the compilation process is 'borked'. Anyone seen this? Solutions?

This is a pure AS project, and so should have no dependency on the Flex SDK, howver, it seeems to be inextricably linked to the Flex 4.x SDK and Flash Player 10+. I have tried `swf-version` and `-target-player-version` in the compiler arguments, but there is still something I am missing to get this to compile for Flash player 9.

Comment: Yes! Just solved.. it was the angle brackets in the Vector definitions, tripping up the compiler and giving some non-obvious error messages. If you post it as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: You may consider using ActionScript only project if the project has no dependencies to the Flex SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might well have used classes or methods that were not available in the 3.6 SDK. Even rather common ones, such as Vector, can only be used in FP > 10.

Comment: Yes! Just solved.. it was the angle brackets in the Vector definitions, tripping up the compiler and giving some non-obvious error messages